# Explanation of Pattern for text tokenizer

Tags: python, nlp, nltk

I'd like to know exactly what is being done to text using the specified pattern in this tokenizer:

```
from nltk.tokenize import RegexpTokenizer
tokenizer = RegexpTokenizer(r'[a-zA-Z]\w+\'?\w*')
text_token = text.apply(tokenizer.tokenize)
```

Where "text" is a pandas series, each row being a sentence.

I specifically want to understand the *r'[a-zA-Z]\w+\'?\w*'* part. Details (explanation of each component) would be appreciated.

Comment: See https://regex101.com/r/FCLf7r/2

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's asking for "why is this code working?"

Comment: Maybe this is clearer https://regex101.com/r/FCLf7r/4

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is called a regular expression or [regex](https://medium.com/factory-mind/regex-tutorial-a-simple-cheatsheet-by-examples-649dc1c3f285). In

`[a-zA-Z]\w+\'?\w*`

- `[a-zA-Z]` stands for a single character from `a` to `z` or from `A`
  to `Z`
- `\w+` matches any repeated word character, where `\w` is
  shorthand for `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` and `+` sign allows its repetition
- `\'?` matches the character `'` literally
- `\w*` is word character again, repeated from one to infinite amount of times

For instance, string `Random01'example` is matched by this expression. [This site](https://regex101.com/r/i8UZsi/2) also explains it well.